# Swift protocol conformance with async overload

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, async-await, protocols

Why does this successfully compile and run? (Swift 5.8)

```
protocol AsyncOverloaded {
    func load()
    func load() async throws
}

class MyClass: AsyncOverloaded {
    func load() {
        print("load called")
    }
}

let myClass = MyClass()
myClass.load()
// prints "load called"
```

To my understanding `MyClass` does actually not conform to protocol `AsyncOverloaded`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note, when you `try await myClass.load()` from an asynchronous context, the compiler will warn you (but, not a hard error) that it cannot resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `load()` in `MyClass` satisfies both protocol requirements.

A non throwing function satisfies a requirement for a throwing function since it's just like a throwing function that never actually throws. Similarly a synchronous function can satisfy an `async` requirement.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference for that? Some documentation?

Comment: @Darko - See `S2` in [SE-0296 - Async/await - Protocol conformance](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0296-async-await.md#protocol-conformance). That’s focusing on a synchronous function that satisfies the `async` requirement, but you get the idea.